# Can I restore an entire project from local history in one step?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I can replace an individual file with a version from local history by right clicking the file in the package explorer.

Is there a way to replace an entire project or package with local history of a given time stamp in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is not possible, I submitted an Eclipse [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384525).

Comment: I would have created it for Platform, not for JDT.