# How to watch last project changes in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, customization

I develop application in eclipse.

After some steps I understood that my application doesn't work.

I want to see last changes in project that to understand what caused the bug. I don't remember all steps.

Is it really to watch in eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can easyly do that in Eclipse. Just right-click the file and select Team -> show in History to see what changed in this file.

You can configure how much history should be saved in your preferences.

To manage versions of your software / code you should look at git or other revisition controll tools like that.
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) for an overview.

Comment: I know about it but I want to watch **project changes**

Comment: for example: 12-39 - Class1.java was changed; 12-38 Class2.java was changed

Comment: As said in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376141/can-i-restore-an-entire-project-from-local-history-in-one-step) this does not seem possible... :(

Comment: For individual files you can use `Compare With / Local History` to see changes. I don't think there is anything to show all changes in the projects

Comment: if eclipse had this function I would use it very often.

Comment: Thats why a revision controll system should be used like always. ;)